# Chrome App inside an Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a Chrome app but I need it to be accessible from any web page the user is viewing as the app is supposed to interact with the content of the page. From what I have seen, this is only done through extensions, but apps are the only ones that have the file system permissions needed to do what I am trying to accomplish.

Is it possible wrap a Chrome app with a Chrome extension to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to write both an app and an extension that interact through [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external).

Your question is a bit unclear as to what you want to achieve (a single item? then, no), but it's the best approximation.

Comment: Agree. If you need to use features that are restricted to extensions, you should write extension, app, and then just transfer calls from extension to app.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I'm about 99.99% sure the answer is no.

Comment: You can certainly use an extension and an app together to achieve a task. There are plenty that do that already in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Yes. I was answering the OP's question.